# Points of discontinuity of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left\{n x \right\}}{n^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity, fractional-part

I know that a similar question was in Riemann's thesis (see if you have the paper [$1$] where it is referred) Could you provide details of this *new* example in my Question?

**Edited:** I don't know how define $ \left\{ x \right\} $, see Riemann thesis and the first section of [1], because is defined a function $ \left\{ x \right\} $, to get a similar example.

> **Question.** How do you calculate the points where $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left\{n x \right\}}{n^4}$$ is discontinuous? And, what is the jump in each of these points?  **Thanks.**

Thus I am asking an easy way to get a closed form of the points of discontinuity of our $f(x)$ and how one can calculate the jusp in each of them.

### **References:**

[$1$] Córdoba, [*Encounters at the interface between
Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis*](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/acordoba/documentos/articulos/EncountersAtTheInterfaceBetweenNumberTheoryAndHarmonicAnalysis.pdf), Proceedings of the "Segundas Jornadas de Teoría de Numeros" (Madrid, 2007), Biblioteca de la Revista Matematica Iberoamericana. I say the page before the second section.

Comment: I add this code with [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com) to know an *approximation* of the graph of our series, I understand that isn't right because our series is infinite and I am saying to WA that draw a finite series: *sum frac(nx)/n^4, from n=1 to 10*

Comment: Why you have only 46 rep even though having asked more than 100 questions ?

Comment: Obviously, this function is discontinuous at all rational points, because $nx$ has jumps at $x=m/n$, and all $n$ are present. And you know the jump of the numerator is $1$, so all you need is take the sum of jumps which coincide.

Comment: Thanks, I spent my reputation in bounties, but the right is have good answers. You are welcome @A---B

Comment: I accept your words, but from the example in [1], **I believe** that there is a condition different of yours to get the closed form of the points of discontinuity and the value of the jump. Many thanks @orion

Comment: It may be... useful to summarize what [1] states and obtains, for those who do not have access to it and for the sake of making the question self-contained.

Comment: Was a confussion from my words, then I am saying to you that you are welcome, and you can search the paper and find from hands of the author. Many thanks @ClementC

Comment: I don't understand your comment. All I am suggesting is: edit your question to state what [1] says about it. You ask a question referring to a paper, you should not presume people will embark on a quest to find that paper, identify the relevant part, and then come back, just for the sake of understanding what you ask.

Comment: @ClementC. I was editing my post, because I don't understand well myself problem, thanks a lot for your advice.

Comment: So, your first question is notational, namely "what is $\{x\}$?"? It usually is the fractional part of $x$, i.e. $x-\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Comment: Many thanks and thanks for your patience, yours and the user below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's observe the jump at a rational point $x=p/q$, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$. The function $\{x\}$ has a jump of $-1$ at every whole number. So, for $x=p/q$, the jumps are at $n=mq$ for each $m$. Renumber the sum and you get:

$$\text{jump}(p/q)=\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{(mq)^4}=-\frac{1}{q^4}\zeta(4)$$

Comment: I was edting my question, a moment please, and I am sorry because I don't know what's is {x}.

Comment: Then you state that my genuine {x}, is the fractional part function? Many thanks.

Comment: That's how I understood your question, yes.

Comment: Many thanks, I was editing , that was the problem, and that I didn't undertstad my question.